# Custom cookie for ASP.Net FormsAuthentication + SqlMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net, .net, cookies, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

I am setting up a new subsite that is using a different technology than my main application. ex: "~/subapp/" ... this site needs to be able to read/write the authentication cookie that is being used.  The main site is using SQL Membership, Roles and Profiles

I'm hoping that there is something relatively simple I can override with the FormsAuthentication bits so that I can write a cookie in a different encrypted format that both sides can read/write.

Barring that is there any documentation on the authentication cookie's structure/encryption used?  I know I'll have to hard-code the machine.config, and in the new app so that they share the same keys.

**Note:** When you simply override the Application_AuthenticateRequest in the global.asax.cs, when there is a membership provider, the provider seems to override what you specify in the global.asax ...

Comment: There is code all over the existing app that utilizes the built in providers... and don't want to disturb that if I can avoid it.  The new sub-app is in nodejs/express, using tedious for SQL access.